# Is it possible to open multiple VSCode windows at the same time?

Tags: visual-studio-code

With PyCharm, I can have multiple windows for projects at the same time.

[image]

Is it possible to do that with VSCode?

Comment: I don't think so, unless someone else has figured out how to do that. You can open instances of vscode but that'll be different windows.

Comment: @zedfoxus "but that'll be different windows" - isn't that what OP is asking for? `code ~/repo/proj1 && code ~/repo/proj2`?

Comment: I'm using it in Linux (Ubuntu 20.04 using snap), and.. no, it cannot separate into windows for some reason. The worst thing for me is that I can't even open multiple instances unless I'm using the terminal. I'm guessing it's because of the electron framework, but I highly doubt it. Also, I remember using this feature some time, maybe they removed it or it's just a Mandela effect from me.

Comment: @JBallin that could be. I assumed that PyCharm opened 2 projects in a single window but split vertically. I shouldn't have assumed.

Comment: @ChrisGeorge I posted an answer. Does that method work for you on Ubuntu 20.04 with VSCode?

Comment: @JBallin thank you for raising the point about what the OP was looking for. I was shortsighted in understanding OPs needs. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am using this build:

```
Version: 1.45.1
Commit: 5763d909d5f12fe19f215cbfdd29a91c0fa9208a
Date: 2020-05-14T08:33:47.663Z
Electron: 7.2.4
Chrome: 78.0.3904.130
Node.js: 12.8.1
V8: 7.8.279.23-electron.0
OS: Darwin x64 19.4.0
```

If you want to open 2 windows - one with project 1 and the other with project 2, you could do this:

Open Visual Studio Code > File > New Window (or press `Shift`+`Command`+`N`)

[image: Open VS Code]

That opens 2 different instances in their respective windows.

[image: Another window of VS Code]

## Command line

Assuming `code`, the executable, is in your PATH, you could open multiple instances in their respective windows.

Let's say you had 2 directories: project1 and project2 like so:

```
~ % ls -h project*
project1:
test.py

project2:
hello.php
```

You can do this:

```
cd project1
code .

# Let VS Code come up

cd ../project2
code .

# Another instance of VS Code will come up
```

[image: Opening VSCode from command line]